# Postgres regular expressions and regexp_split_to_array

Tags: regex, postgresql

In postgresql, I need to extract the first two words in the value for a given column.  So if the value is "hello world moon and stars" or "hello world moon" or even just "hello world", I need "hello world".

I was hoping to use `regexp_split_to_array` but it doesn't seem that I can use this and access the elements returned in the same query?

Do I need to create a function for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 23):

I can't believe that 5 years ago and no one noticed that you can access elements from **regexp_split_to_array** function if you surround them with parenthesis.

I saw many people tried to access the elements of the table like this:

```
select regexp_split_to_array(my_field, E'my_pattern')[1] from my_table
```

The previous will return an error, but the following will not :

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(my_field, E'my_pattern'))[1] from my_table
```

Comment: Very important note! I spent some hours with googling this. The problem is that both `regexp_split_to_array()` and `regexp_matches()` gives the result as an array even the regexp returns a single string only.

Answer (score 10):

You can use POSIX regular expressions with PostgreSQL's [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL):

```
select substring('hello world moon' from E'^\\w+\\s+\\w+');
```

Or with a very liberal interpretation of what a word is:

```
select substring('it''s a nice day' from E'^\\S+\\s+\\S+');
```

Note the `\S` (non-whitespace) instead of `\w` ("word" character, essentially alphanumeric plus underscore).

Don't forget all the extra quoting nonsense though:

- The `E''` to tell PostgreSQL that you're using [extending escaping](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).
- And then double backslashes to get single backslashes past the string parser and in to the regular expression parser.

If you really want to use [`regexp_split_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), then you can but the above quoting issues apply and I think you'd want to slice off just the first two elements of the array:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array('hello world moon', E'\\s+'))[1:2];
```

I'd guess that the escaping was causing some confusion; I usually end up adding backslashes until it works and then I pick it apart until I understand why I needed the number of backslashes that I ended up using. Or maybe the extra parentheses and array slicing syntax was an issue (it was for me but a bit of experimentation sorted it out).

Comment: You can use the [dollar-quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) string syntax to avoid the double backslashes: `$$^\w+\s+\w+$$`

Comment: @Joey Adams: But then you run into issues with regular expressions that are anchored at the end. I usually just use `E''` syntax so that I don't have to remember yet another set of quoting rules.

Comment: @mu yes, it's ugly and almost ridiculous, but still far easier IMO than escaping which is IMO a minefield - for anyone else reading these comments, just choose a pattern that doesn't clash with the end, eg: $re$^\w+\s+\w+$$re$

Comment: @mu note that `select substring(E'it\'s a nice day' from E'^\\w+\\s+\\w+');` probably does not give the desired result

Comment: @JackPDouglas: I think we're dangerously close to fighting over vi versus emacs now (for the record: ed(1) is the standard text editor; ed man! man ed!). I find it harder to find the regex in a twisted pile of dollar signs than to mentally undouble the backslashes. In the end, use whatever works and move on to more interesting problems :)

Comment: @JackPDouglas: I think you meant to say `select substring('it''s a nice day' from E'^\\w+\\s+\\w+');`. I added a `\S` version which is probably better.

Comment: @mu didn't know about \S - thanks for that. Don't disagree with what you say about which kind of quoting to use - what sways it for me are the times when I've had to escape my escapes! Horses for courses as you say. PS, you can call me @Jack :-)

Answer (score 2):

found one answer:

```
select split_part('hello world moon', ' ', 1) || ' ' || split_part('hello world moon', ' ', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(my_text from $$^\S+\s+\S+$$) from v;

  substring
-------------
 hello world
 hello world
 hello world
(3 rows)
```

where for the purpose of demonstration, v is:

```
create view v as select 'hello world moon and stars' as my_text union all 
                 select 'hello world mood' union all 
                 select 'hello world';
```

if you want to ignore whitespace at the beginning:

```
select substring(my_text from $$^\s*\S+\s+\S+$$) from v;
```

Comment: I still prefer the `regexp_split_to_array(text, E'\\s+'))[1:2]` approach, that seems to match the intent better than messing around with `substring` and what a "word" is.

Comment: @mu I'd be concerned about how heavy that would be on my system when the strings are long. There is no reason to suppose from the question that there aren't tens of thousands of words in the field

Comment: True enough. Hard to say what the best approach would be without more details and, most importantly, experimentation on real data. I tend to start with clarity and a direct expression of my intent; if that isn't good enough, then it is time for cleverness and cycle bumming.